# Adding 1000 subscribers to a list

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, php, subscriber

I am trying to create and add multiple subscribers to a list all at the same time through the Marketing Cloud API.

Currently I am able to add them individually, which works but it takes roughly 10 minutes. We have nearly 1000 subscribers to add to a list, and it would be ideal if we could do this pretty quickly.

I've combed through the documentation and the forum and I'm unable to find anything that could help me.

Can I upload a csv file from php using the Fuel SDK?

Can I add multiple subscribers in one SOAP or REST request?

Comment: What does the php tag have to do with this question?

Answer (score 0):

You could just go to the detail page of your list and click on the "Import"-button, where you upload the csv-file. No need for PHP here.

*IMPORTANT:* Enhanced FTP-Feature needs to be enabled as the csv will be placed there temporarily.

**EDIT:** In the comments the asker added, that the import needs to be triggered programmatically, but the SOAP-API doesn't need to be used, so here is a possible solution for this:

1. Create a triggered automation in Automation Studio

   - This is triggered on upload of a csv-file with a given pattern.
   - Next activity in the automation is an "Import Activity" that imports the uploaded csv-file. Select your list as destination and define a mapping for the fields of the csv and the fields in the list.
2. In your program use an ftp-library to upload your csv-file to the "Import"-folder of your Marketing Cloud Enhanced FTP.

**Related documentation articles:**

- [Update a List or Data Extension Using an External File](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_an_import_activity/update_a_list_or_data_extension_using_an_external_file/)
- [Triggered Automations](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/)
- [Importing into a list](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/lists_for_interactive_marketing_hub/importing_into_a_list/)

Comment: Sorry Markus, I think I confused you. I'm looking to add it with the api and only the api. It's for some integrations we're doing with the api

Comment: SOAP API will have performance issues and will be time consuming too. You can use REST but it can only load into a Data Extension.

Comment: OK do you need to do it programmatically only (so you need to add the subscribers from a program/website of yours) or does it really have to utilize the SOAP-API? As Maneesh already mentioned that won't be possible without performance issues. For just a program triggered import I'd have another solution for your.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be done programmatically. I can use either api, but I need them to be imported into the list

Comment: @Riley I updated my answer with a solution that can be triggered from your program and does the import via a csv file.